# Can't boot from bootable Win 7 usb

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

I have a problem with installing new Windows 7 (and format disk) on **ASUS K50ij**. Since I haven't CD/DVD ROM, I've decided to do it using **booting USB**. The problem is, that computer starts as usual after turn on computer.

I've created two bootable USB's, one is using **NTFS** and second is using **FAT32** (using Windows 7 USB tool)
Both are **16 GB Lexar** type.

Of course, I had a look into **BIOS** and tried to set **BOOT priority** to USB. Unfortunately there is no option like USB so I tried **Removable Device** option. I also have them put into USB port when I turned on computer.

This is my BIOS: [image: This is my BIOS]

And this is a tab where should I set the BOOT priority: 
[image]

Have you any experiences with this problem? What should I do?

EDIT: There is one another option about which I'm thinking. Just turn on a computer and Windows, and start setup.exe in USB manually. But I'm affraid there could be the problem I don't know about.

Comment: press F11 or F12 at boot and look if this invokes the boot manager

Comment: @magicandre1981 I tried it and nothing happend, Windows started normally.

Comment: usb legacy support enabled in bios?

Comment: @Dan I have read that I should enable/disable usb legacy but I didn't find it in BIOS.

Comment: Can you make pictures of `advanced` and `boot` setup pages? Also check techie007's answer, many bioses do have a separate option for hard drive order and list the stick as a hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Determine if the BIOS detecting the USB stick as a Removable Device or a Hard Drive (the *Type* of device).
2. Check other areas of the BIOS (go up a level from where you are in the boot menu) for options to set the individual device order within the device type. For example, if you have more than one Hard Drive (which the USB device may/probably has been detected as) you can define the type's order, so that you can assign which physical device is the "Hard Drive" referred to in the Boor Device Priority menu you've shown.

[image]

[Source (the Manual for your motherboard)](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Asus/K50IJ/Manual/248199?page=74)